# Result is not displayed in proper order in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have tried to display results from a table in sqlite3 database. I've tried .mode to column and ".header on", but the way it is displaying is not good. 
This is the output. Can anyone please let me know how to solve this issue?

```
<pre>
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> SELECT * FROM pets;
_id         name        breed       gender      weight    ␞----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------␞1           Tommy       Pomeranian  1           4         ␞2           Garfield    Tabby       1           14        ␞3           Binx        Bombay      1           6         ␞4           Binx        Bombay      1           6         ␞sqlite>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.mode ascii`, columns and rows are separated with unusual control characters in the output.

In theory, `.mode column` switches this back, but before `sqlite3` version 3.17, it restored only the column separator, and left the old row separator. You should update your command-line shell; or as a workaround, execute `.separator \t \n`.